# Shortcut to unpack an assembly and copy it to a given folder?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a fairly simple Maven assembly which I'd like to deploy to a folder on the filesystem. I could definitely just chain my Maven build with an extraction command, but is there a way to do the following from within Maven by passing it a property of where to deploy the files to?

```
mvn install && tar -C /my/deployment/folder xvzf target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-default.tar.gz ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-default/
```

Is there a way that I could provide Maven some configuration so I could do something like:

```
mvn install deploy -DdeploymentDir=/my/deployment/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

use dir `<format>dir</format>` to obtain an unpacked dir

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>path/to/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

assembly.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK"?>
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.1">
        <id></id>
        <baseDirectory>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-default/</baseDirectory>
        <formats>
            <format>dir</format>
        </formats>

        <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>../../path/to/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-default/</directory>
                <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/**</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
    </assembly>
```

use antrun to copy to dest dir

```
    <plugin>   
       <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>    
         <executions>     
        <execution>
        <phase> ... choose after assembly </phase>        
               <goals>            
                     <goal>run</goal>        
               </goals>             
               <configuration>       
                     <tasks>          
                         <copy todir="/tmp/xx" >        
                        <fileset dir="target/${project.build.finalName}"/>
                </copy>
                     </tasks>          
               </configuration>        
        </execution>    
         </executions>  
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This doesn't unpack, it only creates an assembly. I already have a Maven assembly, I need a way to unpack and copy a completed assembly to a folder.